# How to initialize a slice of maps correctly

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

So I want to be able to create a slice of maps such that when I access any element of the slice, I get a not-nil map.

Here is my code so far. But I get the error of `panic: assignment to entry in nil map`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    all := make([]map[string]string, 3)
    first := all[0]
    first["hello"] = "world"
    fmt.Println(all)
}
```

Comment: `all[0] = map[string]string{"hello": "world"}`. Take the Tour of Go (once more).

Answer (score 3):

I think the author wants to pre-init the slice with default instances like so

```
func main() {
    all := make([]map[string]string, 3)
    for idx, _ := range all {
      all[idx] = map[string]string{}
    }
    first := all[0]
    first["hello"] = "world"
    fmt.Println(all)
}
```

Comment: This works. But I was asking to see if there is any other simpler, more native go like method to deep initialize. Thanks anyways :)